# How to provide GUI interface to all users of Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gui

I have "Ubuntu Dekstop" installed in VirtualBox in a Windows 7 PC.
How can I configure it to provide a GUI interface to every user I create in the Ubuntu?
Should I install "Ubuntu Server" to accomplish this?
Can this be done in Ubuntu? I remember working in a place where solaris was intalled in a server and every user used to login using cygwin and get a solaris GUI desktop.
Can this be done? And what is this feature called?

I am asking this for an event for the following purpose.
I want to install ruby on rails in an ubuntu machine and create 5 users in the ubuntu.
These 5 users will have their own Windows 7 laptops.
These 5 users should be able to get their own GUI desktop on their Windows 7 laptop.
And can this be done by installing Ubuntu in Virtual Box in a Windows 7 PC? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to accomplish this:

- You can use a tool such as UltraVNC to remotely connect to the Ubuntu machine. Thanks to Google I found [this IBM page](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/os-multiuserloginsvnc/index.html) explaining what you have to do to set everything up.

OR, if your company has any restrictions regarding VNC tools,

- You could use X Forwarding when establishing an SSH connection, along with a tool such as [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/%E2%80%8E) or Cygwin's own *Xwin* X server. This has to be explicitly allowed on the Ubuntu machine's */etc/ssh/sshd_config* by adding

  ```
  X11Forwarding yes
  ```

This will allow you to start a *gnome-session* via ssh.

Hope it helps :)